# Sending a local image with post request discord API

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord

Im currently able to send a message with content and embed, and with the embed I can set an image through a URL. I can't figure out what [this](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files) page of the docs says, I don't understand which is the header, which is the attachment and so on. I tried every possible way but I can't seem to make it work. How can I send a local image to Discord using attachments? 
 I tried with this: 
**This is the message event**

```
const atc = new Attachment({
      id: "232",
      filename: "ciao.gif",
      url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saverioscagnoli/pokemon-local/master/normal/drilbur.gif",
      proxy_url:
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saverioscagnoli/pokemon-local/master/normal/drilbur.gif",
      size: 100,
      content_type: "image/gif",
    });
    const ebd = new Embed({
      color: EMBED_COLOR,
      image: {
        url: "attachment://ciao.gif",
      },
    });
    await msg.reply({ content: "Pong", embeds: [ebd], attachments: [atc] });
```

**This is the reply function**

```
try {
        const req = await request(
          API_URL + "channels/" + this.channel_id + "/messages",
          {
            headers,
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              content,
              embeds,
              attachments,
              message_reference: ref
                ? {
                    message_id: this.id,
                    channel_id: this.channel_id,
                  }
                : null,
            }),
          }
        );
        if (req.statusCode != 200) {
          throw new Error("Bad request! code: " + req.statusCode);
        } else return 200;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
```

I tried changing the `content-type` of the headers to `multipart/form-data` but it doesn't work